# Question about localisation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. $S$ be a multiplicative closed subset of $A$. Suppose it is given that $A_S$ is a local ring. What can we say about $S$. Is it true that $S$ must be a complement of a prime ideal?

Thank you.

Comment: What does $A_S$ denote?

Comment: I think It means localization of $S$.

Comment: You can find your answer in there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088469/is-the-complement-of-a-prime-ideal-closed-under-both-addition-and-multiplication

Comment: It seems dublicated.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 That question assumes $S$ is the complement of a prime ideal, and asks if $S$ is multiplicatively closed. This question assumes $S$ is multiplicatively closed and that $R_S$ is local, and asks about $R\setminus S$. So... it is clearly *not* a duplicate of *that* question. But I have a feeling it still might be a duplicate of a different question.

Comment: I found the duplicate.